# Event creation / trigger with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, firefox-addon

I currently use the following code to trigger an event from my Firefox Add-On.

```
    var hiddenArea = document.getElementById("section_help");
    if (hiddenArea) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        hiddenArea.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
```

I tried to achieve the same with jQuery using

```
$("#section_help").trigger("click");
```

but it doesn't work.
jQuery doesn't trigger the event that was embedded by the original code.

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) mentions the following:

> Although .trigger() simulates an event activation, complete with a
>   synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a
>   naturally-occurring event.

It's not really clear what they mean by that so I had to look at the source code. Apparently, jQuery doesn't really create a native event object. It will merely trigger its own event handlers (the ones added via jQuery) and whatever it can find in `onfoo` properties. Event handlers added via `addEventListener()` won't be triggered. Native actions associated with the event won't be triggered (jQuery seems to be handling a few special cases however).

To sum up: better stick with your old way of creating events. It might be more verbose but it does what you expect.